# How to scale SVG's children on IE

Tags: css, svg, transform

Look at this Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wmn63d68/7/

HTML :

```
 <svg id="hexagone" x="0px" y="0px" width="400px" height="400px" viewBox="0 0 400 400" enable-background="new 0 0 400 400" xml:space="preserve">
  <polygon points="397.731,198.75 299.798,368.5 103.933,368.5 6,198.75 103.933,29 299.798,29 " />
</svg>
```

CSS :

```
  svg#hexagone polygon {
   transform-origin: 50% 50%;
   fill: transparent;
   stroke-width: 3;
   stroke: blue;
 }

 svg#hexagone polygon {
   transform: scale(0.5);
   -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
 }
```

As you can see, the scale works perfectly on Chrome, FF... However it does not work on IE (all the transform properties). It only works on tags like div or svg but not on svg's childrens (path, polygon, rect...).

Maybe someone has an idea ?

Comment: You'd need to specify the transforms as attributes rather than via CSS if you want it to work on IE.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/SVG/SVG_und_CSS#IE-Bug:_Ansprechen_von_Kindelementen) (in German) states that IE can't handle CSS selectors of descendants within SVG elements. Also mentioned [here](https://css-tricks.com/gotchas-on-getting-svg-into-production/): `svg.parent path.child { /* won't work! */ }`

I posted a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41963388/css-selector-for-svg-use-descendants-ie-workaround-wanted) on SO.

Assigning a class or id to `polygon` itself would make it selectable directly and thus even in IE.