# CSS selector for SVG <use> descendants - IE workaround wanted

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

My inline SVG mimics a three-digit seven-segment (*en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display*) LED indicator. Due to reusable groups of segments I coded these seven once and placed it by `<use>` element three times. Due to repeating characters, I encoded each character pattern once with CSS selectors, turning on respective segments. Example:

[image: This is how it should look like]

Apparently, it [doesn't work in IE](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/SVG/SVG_und_CSS#IE-Bug:_Ansprechen_von_Kindelementen), at least at time of writing this. As far as I understood it, IE can't handle CSS selectors of descendants within SVG elements. **EDIT**: also mentioned here: *css-tricks.com/gotchas-on-getting-svg-into-production/*, `svg.parent path.child { /* won't work! */ }`

Any ideas of a workaround other than brute force cloning instead of `<use>`? I tried replacing classes with ids, without success. I'm looking for a solution without JavaScript.

The individual polygons only have their own classes, like `.a7`, this is why I have to know its parent in order to apply the fill color. Is there a way to  let browser prepend parent's class to element's class, like `<polygon class="WhatEverClassMyParentHas a7" points=". . ."/>`?

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200px" viewBox="-1 -1 36 20">
    <style type="text/css">
      <![CDATA[ 
      .O .a7,
      .O .b7,
      .O .c7,
      .O .d7,
      .O .e7,
      .O .f7,
      .F .a7,
      .F .e7,
      .F .f7,
      .F .g7 
      {
        fill: red;
      }
      ]]>
    </style>
    <defs>
      <g id="dig7" fill="grey">
        <polygon class="a7" points=" 1, 1  2, 0  8, 0  9, 1  8, 2  2, 2" />
        <polygon class="b7" points=" 9, 1 10, 2 10, 8  9, 9  8, 8  8, 2" />
        <polygon class="c7" points=" 9, 9 10,10 10,16  9,17  8,16  8,10" />
        <polygon class="d7" points=" 9,17  8,18  2,18  1,17  2,16  8,16" />
        <polygon class="e7" points=" 1,17  0,16  0,10  1, 9  2,10  2,16" />
        <polygon class="f7" points=" 1, 9  0, 8  0, 2  1, 1  2, 2  2, 8" />
        <polygon class="g7" points=" 1, 9  2, 8  8, 8  9, 9  8,10  2,10" />
      </g>
    </defs>
    <rect x="-1" y="-1" width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
    <use id="x100" class="O" xlink:href="#dig7" />
    <use id="x10"  class="F" xlink:href="#dig7" transform="translate(12,0)" />
    <use id="x1"   class="F" xlink:href="#dig7" transform="translate(24,0)" />
  </svg>
  <p>This three-digit seven-segment LED indicator should display the word OFF. Segments are turned on by CSS selectors.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The bug you're referencing is about markers and not use elements. The use element is inappropriate for your use case, it's designed to display identical things. You need to use cloning.

Comment: @RobertLongson, by cloning, are you referring to a specific SVG element, a technique like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091555/how-do-i-use-javascript-to-clone-an-svg-element) or rather a copy-paste process, manual or with a preprocessor?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode